# Opening a text file with no xattr gives "Operation not permitted" under macOS Catalina and Python 2

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina, xattr

I've been having trouble getting Python (embarassingly, Python 2 in this case) to open some files on my machine, running macOS Catalina 10.15.6. I've boiled down the issue down to the following. I have two apparently identical text files except with different xattr. Python is willing to open one and not the other. Here's my code:

```
import os, subprocess

for filename in ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]:
    path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/"+filename))
    assert os.path.isfile(path)
    print(filename, " attr:", oct(os.stat(path).st_mode & 0o777))
    print(filename, "xattr:", subprocess.check_output(["xattr", path]).strip())
    try:
        with open(path) as infile:
            print("Succeeded for file", filename)
    except IOError as ioe:
        print(ioe.args[1], "for", filename)
```

Here's the output:

```
file1.txt  attr: 0777
file1.txt xattr: com.apple.macl
Succeeded for file file1.txt
file2.txt  attr: 0777
file2.txt xattr: 
Operation not permitted for file2.txt
```

You might think that the lack of xattr on `file2.txt` is convincing my computer that file2.txt is poison and cannot be trusted, but Emacs is perfectly happy to open it.

"What if you remove the `com.apple.macl` from `file1.txt`?", you ask. Well it turns out that macOS will not allow you to do that, but [there's a workaround](https://www.brunerd.com/blog/2020/01/07/track-and-tackle-com-apple-macl/). And if I do this I do then lose the ability to read `file1.txt` in Python as well.

The files that I can't read were created with no malice--for example, files created in Emacs get this treatment. I'm wondering:

1. What's going on here? Are extended attributes really to blame?
2. How can I get Python to read these benign files which other program on my computer are happy to read?